# Problem of disable_eager_execution with multi-thread

Tags: python, tensorflow

For the following code, if I comment out `tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()`, then the code runs successfully. But if I want to accelerate by adding `tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()`, then an error occurs saying `ValueError: Tensor Tensor("loss/mul:0", shape=(), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.`. Anyone knows what happened and how to solve this? Then keras version is 2.12.0, and tensorflow is 2.12.0.

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor as Executor

tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()

x = np.random.randn(10, 20).astype(np.float32)
y = np.zeros((10, 3))


model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(3, input_shape=(20, ), activation='softmax'))
model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

with Executor(max_workers=2) as executor:
    results = []
    for i in range(2):
        results.append(
            executor.submit(
                model.evaluate, x, y, verbose=0
            )
        )
    accuracy_list = np.array([r.result()[1] for r in results])
```

To explain a little more about the code, I want to evaluate model accuracy in a parallel way. In the above code, I evaluate with the same model weights, but eventually I want to evaluate at different weights. I do not know why the code suddenly fails when I add `tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()`.